# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin\left(\arccos{\left(\frac{\cos{x + 5}}{1 + 2\cos{x}}\right)}\right) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

Evaluate the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin\left(\arccos{\left(\frac{\cos{x + 5}}{1 + 2\cos{x}}\right)}\right) \,dx$$

**Working:**

We get rid of the $\sin$ by considering the triangle. So, $$\sqrt{\left(1+2\cos(x)\right)^2 - \left( \cos(x) + 5 \right)^2}$$

Simplifying we get:
$$\sqrt{\left(1+2\cos(x)\right)^2 - \left( \cos(x) + 5 \right)^2} $$$$ = \sqrt{1 + 4\cos(x) + 4\cos^{2}(x) - \left(\cos^{2}(x) + 10\cos(x) + 25 \right)}$$$$  = \sqrt{3\cos^{2}(x) - 6\cos(x) -24}$$

So the problem transforms into $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sqrt{3\cos^{2}(x) - 6\cos(x) -24}}{1 + 2\cos(x)} \,dx$$

I haven't figured out what to do from here, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At $x=0$, you are taking $\cos^{-1}(2)$, which is not a real number. Is that right?

Comment: Over the whole range of integration $\frac{\cos(x)+5}{1+2\cos(x)}\gt1$. $\arccos$ is usually defined on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Was $\sin\arccos$ meant to be e.g. $\arcsin\cos$?

Comment: @J.G. I'm not sure, I didn't write the question.

Comment: Your manuplations seem correct as *Mathematica* gives the same result for what you start with and what you end with:  $-\frac{2 \left(5 F\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)|\frac{1}{5}\right)+\Pi \left(\frac{3}{5};i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)|\frac{1}{5}\right)-9 \Pi \left(-\frac{1}{5};i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)|\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{5}}$ which is approximately $1.46165 i$.

Comment: where $F$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind and $\Pi$ is the complete elliptic integral of the third kind.

Comment: Note that $\sin\arccos u = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$.

Comment: @Ajay Could you please address the fact that the integrand is not real valued? Do you think this is what the writer of the question intended? Or could there be a typo?

Comment: @DavidH As I mentioned earlier, I did not write the question. This question came up in the finals of the SISMT math olympiad finals.

Comment: @DavidH This is a high school math olympiad for very advanced math students. There were some questions involving theorems not taught in the standard high school math syllabus. So i'm not sure if it is a typo or it is the intended question.

Comment: There were also some other difficult questions like evaluating $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$

Comment: As already indicated by RobJohn (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn), this whole question is a trick question: how do you calculate the integral of a function which is not defined? Don't start calculating: when the function is not defined, then the integral is not defined either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the value of the following definite integral:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}x\,\sin{\left(\arccos{\left(\frac{5+\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}}\right)}\right)}\approx1.46165\,i.$$

As a commenter pointed out, the integral $\mathcal{I}$ can be evaluated in terms of standard elliptic integrals.

---

Observing that

$$\sin{\left(\arccos{\left(z\right)}\right)}=\sqrt{1-z^{2}}=i\sqrt{z^{2}-1};~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{R}},$$

and

$$-\frac{2\pi}{3}<x<\frac{2\pi}{3}\implies1<\frac{5+\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}},$$

we first reduce the integral to one with an algebraic integrand

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}x\,\sin{\left(\arccos{\left(\frac{5+\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}}\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{1-\left[\frac{5+\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}}\right]^{2}}\\
&=i\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{\left[\frac{5+\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}}\right]^{2}-1}\\
&=i\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{\left[5+\cos{\left(x\right)}\right]^{2}-\left[1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}\right]^{2}}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}}\\
&=i\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{\left[4-\cos{\left(x\right)}\right]\left[6+3\cos{\left(x\right)}\right]}}{1+2\cos{\left(x\right)}}\\
&=i\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(4-y\right)\left(6+3y\right)}}{\left(1+2y\right)\sqrt{1-y^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[x=\arccos{\left(y\right)}\right]}\\
&=i\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{3\left(4-y\right)\left(2+y\right)}}{\left(1+2y\right)\sqrt{\left(1-y\right)\left(1+y\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Then, after the right linear fractional transformations, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
i^{-1}\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{3\left(4-y\right)\left(2+y\right)}}{\left(1+2y\right)\sqrt{\left(1-y\right)\left(1+y\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{3\left(\frac{4-y}{2+y}\right)}}{\left(1+2y\right)\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+y}{2+y}\right)\left(\frac{1-y}{2+y}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{1+2\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac23}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{3\left(5-6t\right)}}{\left(1-t\right)\left(3t-1\right)\sqrt{t\left(2-3t\right)}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{1+y}{2+y}=t\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{3+\sqrt{2}}{7}}^{\frac23}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{3\left(5-6t\right)}{\left(1-t\right)\left(3t-1\right)\sqrt{3t\left(2-3t\right)\left(5-6t\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{3+\sqrt{2}}{7}}^{\frac23}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{9}{\left(3t-1\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(1-t\right)}\right]\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3t\left(2-3t\right)\left(5-6t\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{9+3\sqrt{2}}{14}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\frac{3}{\left(2u-1\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(3-2u\right)}\right]\frac{3}{2\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)\left(5-4u\right)}};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac23u\right]}\\
&=\frac32\int_{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}^{0}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{(-5)}{\left(5-4v\right)^{2}}\left[\frac{3}{\left(\frac{5-6v}{5-4v}\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{5-2v}{5-4v}\right)}\right]\frac{\left(5-4v\right)}{5\sqrt{v\left(\frac{1-v}{5-4v}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{5-5v}{5-4v}\right]}\\
&=\frac32\int_{0}^{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}\mathrm{d}v\,\left[\frac{3\left(5-4v\right)}{\left(5-6v\right)}-\frac{\left(5-4v\right)}{\left(5-2v\right)}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{v\left(1-v\right)\left(5-4v\right)}}\\
&=\frac32\int_{0}^{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}\mathrm{d}v\,\left[\frac{5}{\left(5-6v\right)}+\frac{5}{\left(5-2v\right)}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{v\left(1-v\right)\left(5-4v\right)}}\\
&=3\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{5}{\left(5-6x^{2}\right)}+\frac{5}{\left(5-2x^{2}\right)}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(5-4x^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[v=x^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac65x^{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac25x^{2}\right)}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-\frac45x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\Pi{\left(\arcsin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}\right)},\frac65,\frac45\right)}+\Pi{\left(\arcsin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{35-15\sqrt{2}}{62}}\right)},\frac25,\frac45\right)}\right],\\
\end{align}$$

where $\Pi{(\varphi,n,k)}$ is defined for $0<\varphi<\frac{\pi}{2}\land0<k<1\land0<1-n\sin^{2}{\varphi}$ by

$$\Pi{\left(\varphi,n,k\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\sin{\varphi}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1-nx^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-k^{2}x^{2}\right)}}.$$

---